# Confused about BER (Basic Encoding Rules)

Tags: encoding, asn.1, ber

I'm trying to study and understand BER (Basic Encoding Rules).

I've been using the website http://asn1-playground.oss.com/ to experiment with different ASN.1 objects and encoding them using BER.

However, even the *simplest* encodings seem to confuse me.

Let's take a simple ASN.1 schema:

```
World-Schema DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= 
BEGIN
  Human ::= SEQUENCE {
     name UTF8String
  }
END
```

So basically this is just a `SEQUENCE` with a single UTF8String type field called `name`.

An example of a value that matches this sequence would be something like:

```
{ "Bob" }
```

So, using `http://asn1-playground.oss.com/`, I produce the BER encoding of the following data:

```
some-guy Human ::= 
{  
    name "Bob"
}
```

I would expect this to produce one sequence object, followed by a single string object.

What I get is:

```
30 05 80 03 42 6F 62
```

Now, I understand *some* of this encoding.  The first octet, `30`, is the *identifier* which tells us that a `SEQUENCE` type is the first object.  The `30` is `00110000` in binary, which means that we have a `class` of `0`, a PC (primitive/constructed) bit of `1` (meaning constructed), and a tag number of `10000` (16 in decimal) which means `SEQUENCE`

So far so good.  The next value is the LENGTH in bytes of the `SEQUENCE`, which is `05`.

Okay, still so far so good.

But then... I'm ***totally confused*** by the next octet `80`.  What does that mean???  I would have expected a value of 00001100 (for tag number 12, meaning UTF8String.)

The bytes following the `80` are pretty straightforward: the `03` means Length of 3, and the `42 6F 62` is just the UTF8String value itself, `"Bob"`

Answer (score 9):

The 80 is a context-specific tag 0.  Please note that "AUTOMATIC TAGS" is used at the beginning of the module.  This indicates that all SEQUENCE, SET and CHOICE types will have context specific tags for their components starting with [0], and incrementing by 1 for each subsequent component.  This way, you don't have to worry about tag conflicts when creating your messages, especially when dealing with components which are OPTIONAL or have a DEFAULT value.  If you change "AUTOMATIC" to "EXPLICIT" (which I would not recommend) you will see the [UNIVERSAL 12] that you were expecting in the encoding.

Please note that AUTOMATIC TAGS applied only to tags on components of SEQUENCE, SET, or CHOICE.  It does not apply to the top level components, which is why you saw the [UNIVERSAL 16] for the SEQUENCE rather than seeing a context-specific tag there also.

Comment: But then how is a decoder to know that `03 42 6F 62` represents a UTF-8 string?  There is no identifier octet which indicates that the data is a UTF8string type

Comment: You must have the original ASN.1 specification.  From the ASN.1 specification you can infer that the automatic tag used for that field refers to a UTF8String.  If you use an ASN.1 compiler, the information from the ASN.1 specification is retained in the generation of the encoder/decoder so that the implicit tag for that field is associated with UTF8String in that context.

Answer (score 1):

80 indicates context specific class, primitive, tag number 0.  This is there because you specified an AUTOMATIC TAGGING environment, which automatically assigned a [0] tag to field *name* in type *Human*.