# How to express a ASN.1 value with universal tags when encoded using BER encoding rule?

Tags: asn.1

According to  http://asn1-playground.oss.com/, with the following ASN.1 schema,

```
Test DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::=
BEGIN
    A ::= SEQUENCE {
      int INTEGER,
      seq SEQUENCE { int INTEGER, bool BOOLEAN },
      u UTF8String
    }  
END
```

the following value (in the ASN.1 Value Notation format)

```
a A ::= 
{  
    int 1,
    seq { int 2, bool TRUE },
    u "ABC"
}
```

is expressed in the following 18 bytes using BER encoding rule

```
30   10
    80   01   01
    A1   06  
        80   01   02
        81   01   FF
    82   03   414243
```

[which is parsed by CyberChef into the following ASN.1 tree](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Parse_ASN.1_hex_string(0,32)&input=MzAgICAxMAogICAgODAgICAwMSAgIDAxCiAgICBBMSAgIDA2ICAKICAgICAgICA4MCAgIDAxICAgMDIKICAgICAgICA4MSAgIDAxICAgRkYKICAgIDgyICAgMDMgICA0MTQyNDM)

```
SEQUENCE
  [0] 01
  [1]
    [0] 02
    [1] FF
  [2] 414243
```

It thus seems that the value is expressed with application tags. Could you help to comment whether and how the value could be transformed with the universal tags into the following 18 bytes

```
30   10
    02   01   01
    30   06  
        02   01   02
        01   01   FF
    0C   03   414243
```

[which would give the following better ASN.1 tree when parsed by CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Parse_ASN.1_hex_string(0,32)&input=MzAgICAxMAogICAgMDIgICAwMSAgIDAxCiAgICAzMCAgIDA2ICAKICAgICAgICAwMiAgIDAxICAgMDIKICAgICAgICAwMSAgIDAxICAgRkYKICAgIDBDICAgMDMgICA0MTQyNDMg)

```
SEQUENCE
  INTEGER 01..(total 1bytes)..01
  SEQUENCE
    INTEGER 02..(total 1bytes)..02
    BOOLEAN TRUE
  UNKNOWN(0C) 414243
```

Many thanks for your efforts !

Comment: It seems that the value can be expressed with universal tags [if "AUTOMATIC" is changed to "EXPLICIT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453894/confused-about-ber-basic-encoding-rules)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the reason is "AUTOMATIC TAGS" is used at the beginning of the module, enforcing context specific tags for components of all SEQUENCE, SET and CHOICE types. The value can be expressed with universal tags [if "AUTOMATIC" is changed to "EXPLICIT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453894/confused-about-ber-basic-encoding-rules)